# Update based on order

Tags: sql, teradata

Is it possible to update data based on priority defined in column.
I have input data like this

```
id  Start_date   active_flag
1   21-03-2013   N
1   23-03-2013   N
1   22-02-2013   N
1   20-02-2013   N
```

we have to maintain SC2 in our data and have to keep the data for latest date ( i,e 23-02-2013 here) as active in our database.
we will be getting files daily but in some case, we can get files with combined data for 2 days. now I have to make sure all the history is maintained and data with the latest date as active.

My target data will look like

```
id  Start_date  active_flag 
1   21-03-2013  N
1   23-03-2013  Y
1   22-02-2013  N
1   20-02-2013  N
```

but how to write an update which can update data for the column id , based on the order of Start_date.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Loop through each row, in the desired order, one by one? Otherwise, perhaps batch update on a timed basis to ensure correctness of data? Alternatively, modify the way the data/processing is modeled to account for such an issue?

Comment: Is there a primary key in the table?

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #tst(id int,start_data datetime,active_flage varchar(2))
insert into #tst
SELECT 1,'2013-03-21','' UNION
SELECT 1,'2013-03-23','' UNION
SELECT 1,'2013-03-20','' UNION
SELECT 1,'2013-03-19','' UNION
SELECT 1,'2013-03-18','' 

UPDATE #tst set active_flage=CASE when r_Id=1 then 'Y' ELSE 'N' END
FROM #tst a JOIN 
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION by id order by start_data desc) as r_Id,* from #tst)b
ON a.Id=b.Id AND a.start_data=b.start_data

select * from #tst
```

Considering there will not be duplicate date for same id